# Windows 2012 RDS Server asking for Licensing Mode when it's already set?

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop-services, rds, licensing

I have a confusing situation. I'm setting up a 2012 RDS Licensing Server for our environment. I'm checking under the RD Licensing Diagnoser to make sure everything is proper and I keep getting this error: "The licensing mode for Remote Desktop Session Host server is not configured." And Licensing Mode is set to "Not configured". The annoying thing is, I've set this multiple times and it still keeps saying "Not configured". Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: What related events are being logged in the Windows Event logs?

Comment: I've been looking in the event logs and haven't found anything related to licensing yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have actually ran into this on a couple of servers running 2012 R2 recently and this solved it. Must be a 'feature'.

http://www.tbngconsulting.com/blog/bid/404182/Licensing-mode-for-the-Remote-Desktop-Session-Host-is-not-configured

In PowerShell, do the following:

> $obj = gwmi -namespace "Root/CIMV2/TerminalServices"
>   Win32_TerminalServiceSetting 
>   $obj.SetSpecifiedLicenseServerList("licserver.domain.local")

Where *licserver.domain.local* is your licensing server. 
This is  just manually setting the license server to the desired server.

You can do an

> $obj.GetSpecifiedLicenseServerList()

after the first line, and both before and after the second line to check that it took.

Then in the registry, we'll manually set the mode.

HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\RCM\Licensing Core\LicensingMode

Change the DWORD to 2 for Per Device or 4 for Per User.

Finally, Reboot.

Hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

Hit this problem earlier today - identical symptoms on a Server 2012 R2 RDS setup.

The deployment properties showed the licensing mode and license server correctly but licensing diagnosis said the licensing mode was unconfigured and the license server was unspecified (And there were the usual 'this server is in a grace period' messages to confirm that the config was missing).

Since this is the second one of these servers I have rolled out over the last month for this client using the same licensing server from the same installation media using EXACTLY the same steps I was surprised that this was happening - the first installation was fine.

So I checked the deployment - and the rollout wizard had failed to create a session collection on this server.

Look under Remote Desktop Services in Server Manager.
On the overview page at the top you will find that for your deployment type there are links for step 2 & 3. Step 2 has already been completed (or you wouldn;t have reached this point), but you will need to click the blue text (Hyperlink) for step 3 to create a basic session collection.

As soon as I created the collection the warnings stopped and the settings appeared correctly in the licensing diagnosis app.

Basically, until ALL of the steps to create the RDS deployment have been completed, the Interface doesn't seem to commit the settings, so the system  doesn't see the deployment at all (And it appears that the wizard doesn't always complete the whole process).

Hope this helps someone...